# redis sentinel not starting /etc/redis-sentinel.conf is not writable: Permission denied

Tags: redis

redis sentinel was running fine after installation. Now it's not starting up with the following error in the logs.

"Sentinel config file /etc/redis-sentinel.conf is not writable: Permission denied. Exiting..."

Answer (score 1):

selinux set to enforcing mode was preventing redis sentinel from starting up after a reboot of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

if you replace the conf file, make sure user "redis" has permissions to /etc/redis-sentinel.conf

[see the file permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLlVj.png)